# Why can't more than one user be referenced in comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I understand that allowing to reference more than one user in a comment might create noise, but why is it that the limit for referencing is capped at 1?

Sometimes, one would want to respond to the comment of a particular user and bring it to the notice of another who is involved in previous communications instead of writing two separate comments.

Am not asking to make referencing unlimited, but to at least raise it to 2, which I think many feel it is desired / feasible.

Is there a compelling reason to keep the limit capped at 1?

Comment: Also one can just write n comments to ping n people. To me that limitation is arbitrary and doesn't make much sense. Think this is worth discussing about it again.

Comment: When you need to ping multiple users, then you're using the comments wrong. Create a chat instead.

Comment: It does not create noise - it creates a lot of noise. Active users already have to deal with enough notifications as it is to the point where they likely just don't respond to most of them at all, let's not give people the power to add even more. Being involved is something you choose to do personally, other people are not involved in that process. So please, stop having the need to try to keep people in the loop. If they want to, they'll look in periodically to see what's happening.